# Is it possible to add a second company at the same address?

Tags: foursquare

I'm managing a FourSquare presence for a couple of companies that are co-located.  Whenever I try to add the second one, it just disappears.  Is there some special way to handle 2 companies with the same physical location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old question so this might not be possible in the past, but right now it is possible for different venues to have the same address. For example the company I work for and another company are both in the same building. They have different venues and offices, there is a venue for the building, all three venues have the same address and the offices are set that they are located inside the building.

**EDIT**:
Or here is this [café](https://foursquare.com/v/tchibo/4d526313dcce224b60bceb1b) inside this [mall](https://foursquare.com/v/arena-plaza/4b86a275f964a520649331e3). Both having the same address.

Comment: Accepting this one even though I can't verify (we no longer use FourSquare).

Comment: Thanks. But I'll add some reference venues to my answer, so you can actually verify it.